# If I convert a python file from py to exe, what about the module I created that the file imports?

Tags: python, module, auto-py-to-exe

[image: MG3KWS is the directory for this module and KWS is the module itself that I created for the client file]

I created a server and client file and I was about to convert it to exe when I realized that I also need to convert the module it uses to exe. What do I do about the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [Auto PY to EXE uses PyInstaller](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) to do the real work here:

> A .py to .exe converter using a simple graphical interface and PyInstaller in Python.

[PyInstaller will automatically bundle any dependencies it finds](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#analysis-finding-the-files-your-program-needs):

> What other modules and libraries does your script need in order to run? (These are sometimes called its "dependencies".)
>
> To find out, *PyInstaller* finds all the `import` statements in your script. It finds the imported modules and looks in them for `import` statements, and so on recursively, until it has a complete list of modules your script may use.

So as long as you `import` your dependencies somewhere reachable from your main script and your virtual environment is active, you should get the right behaviour automatically.

Note that you'll probably need to build *two* executables: one for your server and a separate one for your client.

Comment: would the dependencies need to be converted to EXE or no like the KWS.py module for example?

Comment: @Crystallean, as long as PyInstaller can find them they'll get included when you build your application. What is `KWS.py`? I thought that was your server code.

Comment: oh the KWS.py is the local python script that I imported within the client script. IT's in the scrnshot Forgot to include the server script in the screenshot lol.

Comment: Yes, I see it in the screenshot (by the way, don't rely on screenshots for critical information; they should only be used to support what is in the question text) but the screenshot doesn't tell me anything about what it contains or how it is used. If you do something like `from MG3KWS import KWS` in `client.py`, when you build an executable from `client.py` PyInstaller will find and include `MG3KWS.KWS`. That's what the second quote in my answer talks about.

Comment: Oh alright thanks!

Comment: terribly sorry! I have a poor habit of not doing that